# Is there a way to use bootstrap classes in react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I can't get bootstrap classes to work with react-bootstrap

I tried using bootstrap classes specifically flex properties in react-bootstrap but it doesn't seem to work. But on the docs it shows an example of them using it "https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/layout/grid/", also the docs seem pretty vague so I went to bootstrap's docs but no avail there either.

I noticed when I change how many Col's (like this col md={4}) I want a specific col element to take up the positioning of this button changes even though it supposed to be in the center why is that ? Here is a example of my code

```
import React from 'react';
import'./Welcome.css';
import { Button, Container, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="welcome">
          <Container>
            <Row className="justify-content-center">
              <Col>
                <Button variant="primary" size="lg">Large button</Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

I'm fairly new to react as well, more so to react-bootstrap but I am very familiar with bootstrap, this has me ready to just use CSS grid or flex and not use bootstrap's grid lol. So if anyone can help me out that would be great and much appreciated.

Comment: What's not working about it? Css for bootstrap?

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets

Comment: the flex properties aren't working when I try to use them they don't align the elements they way I am expecting them to.

Comment: @Tuhin are those JS scripts necessary ? Do I have to add them in the index html file ? I already added the bootstrap cdn link for css. sorry I am such a react noob

Comment: Oh, so the css is working. Do you have an example of what it looks like now?

Comment: Yea I do https://imgur.com/a/wXt68uZ

Comment: Kinda figured it out guys thanks for the answers I just had to play around with react-bootstrap a little bit it works like bootstrap in some cases with class names and stuff but other times its own framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col md={{ order: 'last' }}>First, but last</Col>
    <Col md>Second, but unordered</Col>
    <Col md={{ order: 'first' }}>Third, but first</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```